# how to stop an application and launch Activity from a service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to detect the launch of some application like setting. I creat a service i can get the name of all application, and then start an Activity. I would like to stop the application launched and run the activity in foreground not in backgroound. the code used in my sevice is given below. the new Activity is launched but still in background.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = am
                            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    Log.d("liste des applications ", recentTasks.toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d("Executed app",
                                "Application executed : "
                                        + recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity
                                                .toShortString() + "\t\t ID: "
                                        + recentTasks.get(i).id + "");
                        Log.d("============Executed app ======", recentTasks
                                .get(i).topActivity.getShortClassName());

                        if ((recentTasks.get(i).topActivity.getShortClassName()
                                .equals((".Settings"))) && (printed == false)) {
                            Log.d("*******====testestesttest====***********", recentTasks
                                    .get(i).topActivity.getShortClassName());
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LogAnalyserService.this, LauncherGridActivity.class);
//                          intent.setClass(this, LauncherGridActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent); 

                            printed = true;
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
Process.killProcess( Process.processPid() );
```

But you need to know process's pId.

Comment: omg, didn't notice you want to close "Settings". The answer is "You can't". You CAN kill process, but afaik Setting's process is android global process. And you CAN'T close activity of one application from another.